# Static Site Generators: Do they need to be hosted on a server?

Tags: localhost, web-hosting, static-site

I get "what" they are, and have looked up a LOT of tutorials that talk about how to set them up, but not *where* they get set up. The one instance I found that was similar to what I'm looking for as an answer talked about how you can set up a local host and do dev from your computer.

I also understand that each uses something different to compile it (Ruby, Json, etc...).

I would like to use one, but I don't know if I need to do anything special to my SERVER, or set up my SITE HOST in any specific way first.

Do these compilers need to be ON the host, or are they merely used as a dev tool on the LOCAL? I've seen them used on github within the repositories, thus why my confusion.

Is this an "could go either way" situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use them locally to compile the static files, and then deploy the static files to your server.

For example, a common practice with static site generators such as Jekyll or Middleman is to build the static files on your development machine, and then to run a script that will push the build directory to the `gh-pages` branch of your git repository, where they will be served by GitHub.